# jquery show multiple layer divs

Tags: jquery

I'm wondering how I can show multiple divs after a user clicks on an img link "importantImg" below using jquery (importantImg isn't below but is in my program). The problem is that this is just one snippet of the entire page that also has divs, so I don't want to make my select be "div," I just want to interact with these 4 specific divs. Here's the html that contains the 5 divs:

```
<div id="divLayer1">
<div id="divLayer2" class="alertPod">
    <img src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/{0}/_res/_images/icon_alertMessage.png",   PBS.Cms.Settings.PBSFolderName) %>" />

</div>

<div id = "divLayer3" class="msgPod">
    <div id= "divLayer4" class="messageWrapper">
        <h6>IMPORTANT ANNOUNCEMENT</h6>
        <div class="box">         
            <div id="divLayer5" class="viewport" style="overflow: auto; height: 48px;"  runat="server">
                <p> <%--id= "importantMessage">--%> 
                <asp:Literal ID="ltimportantannouncementTitle" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                <br />
                <asp:Literal ID="ltimportantannouncementSummary" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" ><img id="alertCloseBtn" src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/           {0}/_res/_images/button_alertMsgClose.png", PBS.Cms.Settings.PBSFolderName) %>" /></a>
```

Here's the jquery script I'm using that isn't working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("img#importantImg").click(function () {                
            $("#divLayer1").show(); 
            $("#divLayer2").show(); 
            $("#divLayer3").show();
            $("#divLayer4").show();
            $("#divLayer5").show();                                                
            $("#importantImg").attr("src", "<%=  Page.ResolveUrl("~/{0}/_res/_images/icon_alertMessage.png", PBS.Cms.Settings.PBSFolderName) %>");                               
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: It's general much better (for you and for us) to show rendered code, i.e. what the browser sees after server-side variables have been filled in. It's often impossible to debug otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I updated my post to incorporate what you said about code browser sees after server-side variables have been filled in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things here:

1) You don't need to do a $(document).ready() for every function you have. You can do it once and then put everything inside that.

2) Your example is a bit tricky, since this is a jQuery question and there's ASP code in there. Here's my interpretation of what you're trying to do:

Javascript:
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#show_message').click(function() {
               $('.message').html('This is an important message!');
               $('.alert_pod').show();
            });

```
        $('#hide_message').click(function() {
           $('.alert_pod').hide();
       });
    });
```

HTML:
        
           Show Message
           
               Important Message Goes Here
               Hide Message

I don't know ASP (or whatever you're using), but I suspect that the problem is that some of your elements don't seem to have IDs. You're calling them in the Javascript, but the JS can't find the elements because there is no id="importantImg" as near as I can tell.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I added id's for each element, since you were right that I didn't have id's for some elements. I still had the same problem with text within headerAlertMessage box not showing, and only an empty black box.

Comment: I have an image element that I want to show in addition to text. Would html() still work for this?

Comment: I updated my post to make it easier to understand in order to answer it. Any help? Thanks!